# How much does it cost to eat at Jiro's?

Tags: japan, tokyo, restaurants

How much does it cost to eat a "typical" meal (if we may call that) at the famous Japanese restaurant *[Jiro](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/jiro_dreams_of_sushi/)* in Tokyo, per person?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have an idea of the prices you can go to the [restaurant's website](http://www.sushi-jiro.jp/e-contents/e-oshinagaki.html)!
And when I read the menu web page, it tells the "chef's recommended course" is worth 30,000 yen, which is around 300 euros.